# Coremltools TypeError: Keras layer type not supported

Tags: keras, yolo, coreml, coremltools

I trained a custom YOLOv4 model. Then I converted the weights to .h5 using:

https://github.com/david8862/keras-YOLOv3-model-set/tree/master/tools/model_converter

After that I tried to convert the .h5 to coreml:

```
# Custom activation function
from keras.layers import Activation
from keras import backend as K
from keras.utils.generic_utils import get_custom_objects

def mish(x):
  return x * K.tanh(K.softplus(x))

get_custom_objects().update({'mish': Activation(mish)})

from keras.models import load_model
from keras.utils import CustomObjectScope
from keras.initializers import glorot_uniform

with CustomObjectScope({'GlorotUniform': glorot_uniform()}):
    model = load_model('yolov4_custom.h5', compile=False)

mlModel = coremltools.converters.keras.convert(model,
                                        input_names='image',
                                        image_input_names='image',
                                        input_name_shape_dict={'image': [None, 416, 416, 3]})
```

When invoking ..keras.convert(....) I get the error:

> TypeError: Keras layer of type <class
> 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.Functional'> is not
> supported

Answer (score 0):

The backend math operations in Keras (in your case tanh and softplus) are not layers that can be converted. Instead try using the Layer or Activation versions of the functions to reconstruct the functions.

In general, if you want to a custom layer or activation that is not supported by CoreML, you need to specify the custom function in the convert method and provide a Swift/Objective-C implementation. Here's a good guide to doing such a thing for Swish activation: https://machinethink.net/blog/coreml-custom-layers/